# How to calculate the position of a model attached after rotation [XNA]?

Tags: model, xna, rotation, position, game-engine

I'm programming a basic game on xna. I started to place an object (eg weapon) attached to the right arm of my player. When I move my character forward behind left or right all right. But when I rotates my equipment is not positioned correctly. 
I am fully understands it is necessary to recalculate the new position based on the rotation done but I do not see how. 
Here is my code and pictures
A thousand thank you

```
        //Function that will draw the current item selection in the player's hand            
private void draw_itemActionInUse(Model modelInUse)
            {

                int handIndex = skinningData.BoneIndices["Hand_Right"];

                Matrix[] worldTransforms = animationPlayer.GetWorldTransforms();

                Matrix rotationMatrixCalcul = Matrix.CreateRotationY(player.Rotation.Y);
//Here I calculate the new position of the item, but it does not work
                Vector3 newPosition= Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(player.Position.X, player.Position.Y + 4, player.Position.Z ), rotationMatrixCalcul);
                foreach (ModelMesh mesh in modelInUse.Meshes)
                {
                    foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                    {

                        effect.World =
    worldTransforms[handIndex]
    *
    Matrix.CreateScale(2)
    *
    Matrix.CreateRotationY(player.Rotation.Y)
    *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(newPosition);

                        effect.View = View_;
                        effect.Projection = Projection_;

                        effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                    }

                    mesh.Draw();
                }

            }
```

[image: Position initial]

**Figure A**: 
position: x:0;y:0;z:0
angle : 90
**Figure B**: 
position: x:2;y:4;z:0
angle : 90
[image]
**Figure A**: 
position: x:1;y:0;z:1
angle : 35
**Figure B**: 
position: *How calcul this position ?*
angle : 35

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890820/rotating-objects-attached-to-other-objects/13893855#13893855

Comment: Thanksss !! Do you can write this for a answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890820/rotating-objects-attached-to-other-objects/13893855#13893855), the transformation for the attached object is:

```
Matrix positionRotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-parentPosition) 
                               * Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(parentRotation) 
                               * Matrix.CreateTranslation(parentPosition);
Vector3 translation = Vector3.Transform(parentPosition + relativePosition,
                               positionRotationMatrix);

Matrix worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(scale)
                * Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(rotation)
                * Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(parentRotation)
                * Matrix.CreateTranslation(translation);
```

The variable names are self-explanatory.

Comment: ust a question! "ParentPosition" is equal to the player's position or object?

Comment: @MehdiBugnard the position of the entity that your object is attached to - which might be the player in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I you have to get the rotation from your gun and its position. You then create a new position and rotation for your camera.You can find a very precise and good answer from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203909%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx. The sample code is attached. If the project asks you to register to XBOX before running it, you acn just delete the Xbox project and keep the windows project.