# Moving child objects as parent object rotates

Tags: c#, xna

I have a problem with attempting to move simple models in tandem. I have 20 smaller models attached to a larger model. It's essentially a flying saucer with multiple external cannons. I've seen other questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890820/rotating-objects-attached-to-other-objects/13893855#13893855), that look almost like what I want. However, that just creates the draw translation. I actually need to move the child models in 3d space, because they can be independently destroyed and thus require collision detection. Here's how I'm rotating the parent (in the Update() function):

```
angle += 0.15f;

RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(angle) * MathHelper.PiOver2);
```

I've tried a lot of solutions, but the positioning is always off, so they don't really look attached. This is the closest I've gotten:

```
cannons[x].RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2) * 
Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(angle + cannons[x].angle) * 
MathHelper.PiOver2);

cannons[x].position.X = (float)(Math.Cos(MathHelper.ToRadians(angle + cannons[x].originAngle) *
 MathHelper.PiOver2) * 475) + position.X;

cannons[x].position.Y = (float)(Math.Sin(MathHelper.ToRadians(angle + cannons[x].originAngle) *
 MathHelper.PiOver2) * 475) + position.Y;
```

What did I do wrong in that code? Alternatively, if my approach is completely off, what is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Matrix transformations for everything.

```
class Physics {

 public Vector3 Traslation;
 public Vector3 Scale;
 public Quaternion Rotation;

 public Physics Parent;
 public List<Physics> Children;
 public Matrix World;


 public Update() {
      World =   Matrix.CreateScale(Scale) 
              * Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(Rotation) 
              * Matrix.CreateTranslation;
      if (Parent!=null) {
         World *= Parent.World ;
      }    
      foreach (var child in children) child.Update();         
 }
}
```

Realize that this code it's not optimized and can be improved.

This way you should have a Physics object for your large model and 20 Physics objects for small models, attached to large model through Parent property.

if you need Traslation, Rotation and Scale for your objets in absolute coordinates, you can use Matrix.Decompose method, though its far better passing the World matrix to your shader to transform the vertices.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I use this, won't I have to completely replace all of my position related code?

Comment: The child positions will be related to the parent space, if you move  the large model and update transforms, everything attached to the parent will be moved without changing its translation, and same for rotation and scale, so you don't need to make extrange calculations for your cannons

Comment: +1 for a solution that has no trig function. Euler angles are very unsuitable for do 3D maths. Personally, I would have had a single 4x4 matrix rather than separate values for scale, rotation and translation. I find quaternions to be overkill, being mathmatically more abstract and more complex than matrices. Are there any GPUs that handle quaternions natively? Just waiting for......

Comment: Single matrix can be faster but it's harder to understand, and Quaternions are great for interpolating rotations :)

Comment: @Blau: Yes, quaternions are useful for rotations, I've certainly used them, but mainly for their efficient representation than anything else (4 floats versus 9 for a rotation matrix), But as the OP appears to be fairly new to all this, sticking with matrices would be a good first step. Once you understand the mathematics, moving to quaternions would be much easier. Let him get his head around the idea of hierarchical systems.

Comment: I think I understand most of it, but how do I get the rotation quaternion from the float value I'm currently using?

Comment: You have a static method to build it from your rotation matrix, Quaternion.CreateFromRotationMatrix, as @Skizz noted if you don't feel comfortable with Quaternions you can use a rotation matrix instead, although you will use them at the end